# AMP HTML Leverage Browser Caching

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, pagespeed, amp-html

I'm sorry for my English. I use `AMP.js`. How can I set cache?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Those resources are controlled by Google; this is their problem to fix, not yours.